# Semicolons in C#

Tags: c#

Why are semicolons necessary at the end of each line in C#?
Why can't the complier just know where each line is ended?

Comment: I like to see downvotes instead of closing this question.  why the hell are people closing every question they don't like now?  Why not just vote it down?!?!

Comment: TSJ: I, for one, changed my opionion (I first voted to close it as “subjective and argumentative”) but SO doesn't allow me to recant. For what it's worth, I now think this is a valid question and I actually upvoted it.

Comment: i don't undersatdn why people are downvoting this question.

Comment: I think the tone of the question had a very "Why is C# so stupid" tone to it.  I tried to edit into a better question.

Comment: The extremely argumentative tone of the original question caused me to vote to close.  After Dana's edits and some thoughtful answers, I too have changed my mind.  If it gets close I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: I, too, think it's a valid question. It comes to mind why on earth the language designer decided to require a character on every line.

Comment: The question related not only to C#, but also related to Java, C, C++, ECMAScript. Agree with Dana.

Comment: This is not subjective, this is a very valid question, see my ECMA Script quote below!

Comment: Not a subjective question but still causes pointless discussion. Semi-colons will always be required, it will not change. So the answers that talk about how C# would work without them are moot.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The line terminator character will make you be able to break a statement across multiple lines.

On the other hand, languages like VB have a *line continuation character* (and may raise compile error for semicolon). I personally think it's much cleaner to terminate statements with a semicolon rather than continue using undersscore.

Finally, languages like `JavaScript` (JS) and `Swift` have optional semicolon(s), but at least JS has a convention to always put semicolons (even if not required, which prevents accidents).

Comment: It could be worse.  In FORTRAN, the continuation character had to be in a particular column.

Comment: How often do you continue really long statements across multiple lines? Requiring a semicolon or other character to terminate a line is optimizing for a much rarer case.  Using a line continuation makes much more sense.

Comment: It's not just about `how often`. Actually, in modern LINQ days, I do it many times. However, it's really hard reformat the code. Forgetting continuation character is very common. Inserting a semicolon is a completely non-issue (just like pressing enter at the end of line).

Comment: @Chris - maybe, but it's a question of style and personal taste more than of optimization.

Comment: @Chris - I'm pretty sure it's not an edge case, certainly not any more. With the advent of method chaining and fluent interfaces, one logical line of code (with several methods being chained together) can  span many lines of actual code. Line continuation characters do make this a lot uglier.

Comment: VB.Net 10 removes the need for a line continuation character in the vast majority of scenarios.

Comment: @JaredPar: I think I might consider switching if they replaced "End xx" with braces. :)

Comment: JaredPar, are you serious? I want it!

Comment: @Mehrdad, I found it interesting recently to note that of the 5 purely managed languages MS works on, only 1 is a curly brace language and semicolon (C# vs F#,VB.Net,IronPython and IronRuby)

Comment: @JaredPar: I prefer not to think of those evil thoughts ;) Long live C# :x. Mehrdad feels like a close-minded fundamentalist :))

Comment: @Mehrdad, I have no such luxury. A normal day for me includes programming in 4 languages (C#,C++,VB.Net and PowerShell). An abnormal day adds on F# and produces lots of funny emails as I intermix various syntax's.

Comment: @JaredPar: That's pretty nice, actually. I love switching platforms and languages every now and then, as long as the amount of work done in them is not large. I'm pretty sad since I've been a VB guy a long time ago and I can barely remember `V as String` instead of `string v` when writing in VB. :(

Comment: Languages could actually be implemented without any kind of statement termination symbols. Eiffel is one (bad, imho) example. While this sounds great at first, it renders syntax error messages almost useless, as the compile has difficulties, recovering from errors.

Comment: JaredPar: "A normal day for me includes programming in 4 languages" - Looking for employees? :)

Comment: May be the creators of the language have another opinion!

Comment: I don't really see how this answers the question.  Another had the only real reason why it is required, so that it is not whitespace delmimited.

Comment: Many languages like Python, Ruby, JavaScript, and now Swift and Kotlin, don't require semicolons because it's clear where a series of lines connect and where they don't. C# could do the same.

Comment: The JS convention to always put semicolons is from people who don't know the syntax well enough. It's *just bad*. The **only** situation you need semicolons is to insert them as a prefix when starting a statement with `(` (such as an IIFE) or `[` (array literal). That exception is only necessary because the parser allows newlines between expressions and (function calls | property accesses), which was a bad decision, because property accesses should have been syntactically distinct from array literals anyway. That's what I do and have NEVER, EVER run into a problem related to semicolons.

Answer (score 15):

No, the compiler doesn't know that a line break is for statement termination, nor should it.  It allows you to carry a statement to multilines if you like.

See:

```
string sql = @"SELECT foo
               FROM bar
               WHERE baz=42";
```

Or how about large method overloads:

```
CallMyMethod(thisIsSomethingForArgument1,
             thisIsSomethingForArgument2,
             thisIsSomethingForArgument2,
             thisIsSomethingForArgument3,
             thisIsSomethingForArgument4,
             thisIsSomethingForArgument5,
             thisIsSomethingForArgument6);
```

And the reverse, the semi-colon also allows multi-statement lines:

```
string s = ""; int i = 0;
```

Comment: yet it does know: there's an unterminated string literal.

Comment: "The semi-colon also allows multiline statements:". True but your example is a multi-statement line.

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to allow multiple statements in one line. And your other two examples are exceptionally poor since they do NOT require statement termination in languages such as Python.

Comment: All of your examples could be unambiguously handled without statement terminators.

Comment: Python allows all of your examples without forcing a semicolon, and does use it for multi-statement lines.  For strings, multiple lines are done with triple-quotes. Anything with unclosed matching characters like (, [, or {, will combine lines until they are closed, including method calls.

Comment: Every single one of these examples is 100% unambiguous without the semicolon. The parser expects an expression after `s = ` and then runs into the expression `""`. There's no way that a string literal can incorporate a space character or a type declaration (`int`) after it in a C-like syntax like this. So, that `string s = ""` statement is valid and finished with no ambiguity. The parser could have already known that the `int` could only be the beginning of a new statement, specifically an assignment. Calling yourself "TheSoftwareJedi" is a bit rich if you don't know how to write a parser.

Comment: In fact, if you removed the `@`, the type decs, and the trailing semicolon from all of your examples, they would all be perfectly valid Javascript.

Answer (score 11):

How many statements is this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // <--- should there be a semi-colon here?
Console.WriteLine("foo")
```

Semicolons are needed to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: There is no ambiguity. One language may use semicolon characters to separate statements while another uses newline characters. Where is the ambiguity?

Comment: The ambiguity is in a semi-colon-less C#, which is the language we are talking about.  The excerpt could be one command or 2.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. If the question is, "Why can't we make semicolons optional in C#", then you are right. It would be impossible. But there is no technical reason why C# couldn't have been designed to be line-based, so long as it was defined that way from the start.

Comment: `+somefunc(5)` is not valid C# (CS0201). So technically, that example is not ambiguous. It can only mean two separate statements.

Comment: @EdwardBrey: true, see my other example.

Comment: `(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)` without semicolons isn't ambiguous: `(int i = 0 i < 100 i++)` doesn't look pretty, but it would parse if you had two rules: (a) identifiers and literals separated by whitespace only (no operators) indicated separate statements; (b) rule (a) only applies to whitespace separators after two or more identifiers. I'm not sure if it's the right technical terminology, but I'm considering `int` to be an identifier for the sake of these rules. Of course, even if it's unambiguous, it would be a mess, so the semicolons are good regardless.

Comment: @EdwardBrey:  All those semicolon are unambiguous, but the (hidden) one after the `)` is ambiguous.

Comment: This is more an argument for why you should enforce braces around code blocks, rather than why optional semicolons are a bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

So that whitespace isn't significant except inside identifiers and keywords and such.

Comment: As far as I've ever heard, this is the only really correct answer, though I'm sure there were also compute power and other considerations in the beginning.  I'm surprised it didn't get more upvotes, but even "history of mostly dead languages" CS prof didn't *get* this.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, this is true: if a human could figure out where a statement ends, so can the compiler. This hasn't really caught on yet, and few languages implement anything of that kind. The next version of VB will probably be the first language to implement a proper handling of statements that require neither explicit termination nor line continuation [[source](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2008/02/27/22910.aspx)]. This would allow code like this:

```
Dim a = OneVeryLongExpression +
        AnotherLongExpression
Dim b = 2 * a
```

Let's keep our fingers crossed.

On the other hand, this *does* make parsing much harder and can potentially result in poor error messages (see Haskell).

That said, the reason for C# to use a C-like syntax was probably due to marketing reasons more than anything else: people are already familiar with languages like C, C++ and Java. No need to introduce yet another syntax. This makes sense for a variety of reasons but it obviously inherits a lot of weaknesses from these languages.

Comment: recursive: Python allows this only in a few restricted situations -- VB will allow it basically everwhere if the resulting code is unambiguous. Haskell does this, too.

Comment: This is not true, even one of the comments showed that.  Until the compiler can read my mind it can't *always* be certain what I meant unless I follow at least a few basic rules.

Comment: Andrew: I never said there needn't be any rules. Of course you need still rules but the don't have to be as rigid as C#'s rules.

Answer (score 4):

I personally agree with having a distinct character as a line terminator. It makes it much easier for the compiler to figure out what you are trying to do.

And contrary to popular belief it is not possible 100% of the time to for the compiler to figure out where one statement end and another begins without assistance! There are edge cases where it is ambiguous whether it is a single statement or multiple statements spanning several lines.

Read [this article](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2008/02/27/22910.aspx) from Paul Vick, the technical lead of Visual Basic to see why its not as easy as it sounds.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done. What you refer to is called "semicolon insertion". JavaScript does it with much success, the reason why it is not applied in C# is up to its designers. Maybe they did not know about it, or feared it might cause confusion among programmers.

For more details in semicolon insertion in JavaScript, please refer to the [ECMA-script standard 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) where JavaScript is specified.

I quote from page 22 (in the PDF, page 34):

> - When, as the program is parsed from left
>     to right, the end of the input
>     stream of tokens is  encountered and
>     the parser is unable to parse the
>     input token stream as a single complete
>     ECMA Script Program,
>     then a semicolon isa utomatically inserted at
>     the end of the input stream.
> - When, as
>     the program is parsed from left to right,
>     a token is encountered that is
>     allowed by some  production of
>     the grammar, but
>     the production is a restricted production and the token would be the
>     first token for a terminal or
>     nonterminal immediately following the
>     annotation “[no LineTerminator 
>     here]” with in the restricted production (and there fore such a token is
>     called a restricted token), and  the
>     restricted token is separated fromt he
>     previous token by at least one
>     LineTerminator, then a 
>     semicolon is automatically inserted before the restricted token.
>
> However, there is an additional
>   overriding condition on the preceding
>   rules: a semicolon is never 
>   inserted automatically if
>   the semicolon would then be parsed as an empty statement
>   or if that semicolon 
>   would become one of the two semicolons in the header of a for statement
>   (section 12.6.3).
>
> [...]

The specification document even contains examples!

Comment: Of course, if you want your javascript to minify safely, you're probably already using semicolons everywhere in javascript that you would in C#.

Comment: >>>JavaScript does it with much success; I beg to differ, Javascript is quite lousy at semicolon insertion. See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook

Comment: Another most excellent bit on JavaScripts 'successfull' implementation of semicolon insertion is here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D5xh0ZIEUOE&t=452s

Answer (score 2):

Another good reason for semicolons is to isolate syntax errors.  When syntax errors occur the semicolons allow the compiler to get back on track so that something like

```
a = b + c = d
```

can be disambiguated between

```
a = b + c; = d
```

with the error in the second statement or

```
a = b + ; c = d
```

with the error in the first statement.  Without the semicolons, it can be impossible to say where a statement ends in the presence of a syntax error.  A missing parenthesis might mean that the entire latter half of your program may be considered one giant syntax error rather than being syntax checked line by line.

It also helps the other way - if you meant to write

```
a = b; c = d;
```

but typoed and left out the "c" then without semis it would look like

```
a = b = d
```

which is valid and you'd have a running program with a bad and difficult to locate bug so semicolons can often help catch errors that otherwise would look like valid syntax.  Also, I agree with everybody on readability.  I don't like working in languages without some sort of statement terminator for that reason.

Comment: This is more of an argument for why assignment shouldn't return a value, rather than why optional semicolons are bad

Answer (score 1):

I've been mulling this question a bit and if I may take a guess at the motivations of the language designers:

C# obviously has semicolons because of its heritage from C.  I've been rereading the K&R book lately and it's pretty obvious that Dennis Ritchie really didn't want to force programmers to code the way he thought was best.  The book is rife with comments like, "Although we are not dogmatic about the matter, it does seem that goto statements should be used rarely, if at all" and in the section on functions they mention that they chose one of many format styles, it doesn't matter which one you pick, just be consistent.

So the use of an explicit statement terminator allows the programmer to format their code however they like.  For better or worse, it seems consistent with how C was originally designed: do it your way.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the biggest reason that semicolons are necessary after each statement is familiarity for programmers already familiar with C, C++, and/or Java.  C# inherits many syntactical choices from those languages and is not simply named similarly to them.  Semicolon-terminated statements is just one of the many syntax choices borrowed from those languages.

Answer (score 1):

Semi-colons are a remnant from the C language, when programmers often wanted to save space by combining statements on one line.  i.e.

```
int i; for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) printf("hello world.\n"); printf("%d instance.\n", i);
```

It also helped the compiler, which was not smart enough to simply infer the end of a statement. In almost all cases, combining statements on one line is not looked favorably upon by most c# developers for readability reasons. The above is typically written like so:

```
int i;
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    printf("hello world.\n);
    printf("%d instance.\n", i);
}
```

Very verbose! For modern languages, compilers can easily be developed to infer end of statements. C# could be altered into another language which uses no unnecessary delimiters other than a space and indenting tab, i.e.

```
int i
for i=0 i<10 i++
   printf "hello world.\n"
   printf "%d instance.\n" i
```

That would certainly save some typing and it looks neater. If indents are used rather than spaces, the code becomes much more readable. We can do one better if we allow types to be inferred and make a special case of for, to read, (for [value]=[initial value] to [final value:

```
for i=1 to 10  // i is inferred to be an integer
    printf "hello world.\n"
    printf "%d instance.\n" i
```

Now, its beginning to look like f# and f#, in some ways, is almost like c# without the unnecessary punctuation. However f# lacks so many extras (like special .NET language constructs, code completion and good intellisense). So, in the end f# can be more work than c# or VB.NET to implement, sadly.

Personally, my work required VB.NET and I have been happier not having to deal with semi-colons. C# is a dated language. Linq has allowed me to cut down on the number of lines of code I have to write. Still, if I had the time, I would write a version of c# which had many of the features of f#.

Comment: A good demonstration here of why semicolons and braces are useful- your first one line example is incorrect. "hello world" will be printed 10 times, followed by "10 instance". Only the statement immediately after the 'for' is within the for loop. If you added braces, e.g. format the second example onto a single line, it would work fine.

Answer (score -1):

You could accurately argue that requiring a semicolon to terminate a statement is superfluous.  It is technically possible to remove the semicolon from the C# language and still have it work.  The problem is that it leaves room for misinterpretation by humans.  I would argue that the necessity of semicolons is the disambiguation for the sake of humans, not the compiler.  Without some form of statement delimitation, it is much harder for humans to interpret consise staements such as this:

```
int i = someFlag ? 12 : 5 int j = i + 3
```

The compiler should be able to handle this just fine, but to a human the below looks much better

```
int i = someFlag ? 12 : 5; int j = i + 3;
```